# Kinesis Agent - Processing JSON /XML Input Source files

Tags: amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-agent

My input files are XML or JSON, I was needing help in determining how to configure the agent to process these?  As such its a multiline record, with 1 XML/JSON object per input file.  No preprocessing is needed

As these multi-line records, how best to configure the agent for these 2 formats?

Is it the 'multiLineStartPattern' param that needs setting?  Is it as simple as saying its a '{' as the opening brace for JSON?

Cheers

Comment: Its unfortunate that we don't have answer for this question yet.